# Java SSL sockets not working

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, ssl, applet

I am using TCP/IP sockets to create a client and server applicaton. Originally I was using regular sockets but now I have decided to use SSL for my connection. I have created a keystore  and have tried running my application but it has yet to be successful.

Here is my code for the server

```
public class ArFileServer {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean listening = true;
    ServerSocketFactory serversocketfactory;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;  

    try
    {
        //serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4445);

        serversocketfactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        serverSocket = serversocketfactory.createServerSocket(4445);

        String keystore = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        System.out.println(keystore);

        // infinite loop to continually listen for connection requests made by clients
        while (listening)
        {
            new ClientConnection(serverSocket.accept()).start();

            if (serverSocket != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Connection to client established");
            }
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error could not create socket connection to port, check that port is not busy");
    }
}
}
```

and here is the client code:

```
public class ClientSocket 
{
SocketFactory socketfactory = null;
Socket clientSocket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;


// establish a connection to All Care's server application through socket 4444 (adjust localhost to reflect the IP address that the server
// is being run from)
public ClientSocket()
{
    try
    {
        //clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4445);

        //SocketFactory socketfactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        clientSocket = socketfactory.createSocket("192.168.1.8", 4445);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String truststore = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        System.out.println(truststore);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to All Care Server Application : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I am also using these runtime arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Users\Chris\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ArFile\keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

When I try to print out the truststore it always returns null, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to print out the truststore it always returns null

Because you never set it. All you are doing is printing out the value of a system property. If you didn't set it, it is null.

> what am I doing wrong?

Nothing yet, except printing out meaningless information. But much of your code doesn't make sense:

```
if (serverSocket != null)
{
    System.out.println("Connection to client established");
}
```

`serverSocket` being non-null (a) is inevitable at this point, and (b) doesn't have anything do with the client socket being established, which is inevitable at this point.

```
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error could not create socket connection to port, check that port is not busy");
}
```

An `IOException` at this point could mean many things, but the one thing it doesn't mean is 'cannot create socket connection to port'. It is the *client* that does the connecting: the server *accepts* connections. When you catch an exception, always print *its* message, don't just make up your own.

Comment: the if (serversocket != null) is reachable and it does print when I run the program. I have fixed the catch for the IOException now to print its message, but thats not where my error is

Comment: the issue would appear to be related to reading and writing to the socket. The client and the server can't seem to get a message to one another. Perhaps the input and output streams I am using are not supported with SSL?

Comment: @MatthewPigram `serverSocket` can never be null at that point in the program. You have already executed `serverSocket.accept()`.

Comment: @MatthewPigram You need to define "can't". What happens instead? Error message? Exception? Core dump? Computer explodes? Nothing? Your current client code has no code to either send or receive anything: could that be why no messages get through? NB all streams are compatible with SSL.

Comment: You are right about serverSocket never returning null there, Ill fixx that, however this still doesnt solve my problem. The program simply fails to send and recieve messages on both ends. If I remove anything to do with SSL and simply use regular sockets everything works fine... you can see the working code commented out in the provided code

Answer (score 0):

You need to define both trustStore and keyStore in runtime arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=xxx.ks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=yyy 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=xxx.ks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yyy
```

Both can be same file.

trustStore contains public keys of others.
keyStore contains own keys and certificates.

Comment: They *can* be the same file, but they *shouldn't* be the same file: it doesn't make any sense. And you only need to define a truststore if you are the server *or* the server is demanding client authentication, which isn't happning here.